# Trying to get the row information on clicking a row on table in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  building a simple app in ReactJS that works with a JSON array by calling a certain API. I am then populating the results of the array in a table. What I now want is to click on any row in the table and get those values to pass into some other component. I am wondering how to get the row information using onClick.

Here is my code.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {data: []};
}


componentDidMount() {
   fetch('http://hostname:xxxx/yyyy/zzzz')
  .then(function(response) {
   return response.json();
  })
  .then(items=>this.setState({data: items}));
 } 

fetchAccountDetails () {

}

render(){
var newdata = this.state.data;

        return (
            <table className="m-table">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>AccountName</th>
                            <th>ContractValue</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                      newdata.map(function(account, index){
                        return (
                          <tr key={index} data-item={account}  onClick={this.fetchAccountDetails()}>
                            <td data-title="Account">{account.accountname}</td>
                            <td data-title="Value">{account.negotiatedcontractvalue}</td>
                          </tr>
                              )
                            }
                          )
                    }
                </tbody>
              </table>
            );
        }
    }

export default ParentComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the index of the state element and retrieve from the state array. Also it is not required to copy state to another variable before mapping, you can do it with state itself

```
 render(){

    return (
        <table className="m-table">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>AccountName</th>
                        <th>ContractValue</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                  this.state.data.map((account, index) => {
                    return (
                      <tr key={index} data-item={account}  onClick={() => this.fetchAccountDetails(index)}>
                        <td data-title="Account">{account.accountname}</td>
                        <td data-title="Value">{account.negotiatedcontractvalue}</td>
                      </tr>
                          )
                        }
                      )
                }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        );
    }
}

fetchAccountDetails(index) {
    var values = this.state.data[index];
    console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. I am getting this error when I add onClick property to the row. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchAccountDetails' of undefined at http://localhost:8070/dist/index.js:2558:65  at Array.map (native)`

Comment: Didn't see it, that is a binding issue, use arrow function in map, updated the code for it

Comment: Thanks. I have added those changes. Now, when I refresh the page, in the console, all values are printed without clicking on the rows. 'onClick' seems not to work. Also I have added index parameter while using fetchAccountDetails in 'onClick'

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I had overwritten what was there in my first answer, you need to call onClick like onClick  = {() => {this.fetchAccountDetails(index)}}

Comment: Sure. Can you also tell me how this value can be passed to a different component while clicking on that row.

Comment: Do you want to send it to a child component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145660/discussion-between-midhun-mathew-sunny-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

fetch the value using

```
fetchAccountDetails (event) {

Account:event.target.value
this.getData(Account);
}

getData: function(var account)
this.setState({
        state: account
    });
```

Now you have your data set as state and you can use it anywhere you want yo